# Make the Lead- Company field as unrequired

Tags: apex, administration

I need to make the lead company field  is un required. is there any possibility's?

Answer (score 1):

According to the article found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385311&type=1)

You can remove the required field by **enabling** Person Accounts from Setup. But, please read the article linked above and understand what it does and means when you activate it.

However, if you do not want to do the above, there's a workaround.

1. Create a new custom field in Leads and put a label of **Company**. Once you have created this you will get a unique API name, for example **Company__c**.
2. Upgrade your lead record page to a **Dynamic Forms** (to do this you can follow the instructions [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_migrate.htm&type=5)).
3. Once upgraded, remove the Company (standard field) from the page layout from the same "Edit Page" screen and then drag and drop your Custom Company field that you created from Step 1 and click **Save**.
   **Note:** When you click save after step 3, salesforce might give you a small warning but it's fine, we will prepopulate the required fields, in the instructions below.
4. Now create a new record-trigger flow, configure the trigger to run when created and updated and choose **Fast Field Updates**.
5. For your next flow element, you can **Update Triggering Record** and set the **Standard Company** field value to anything you want for example I just write "test" (without the "").
6. That's all save and activate your flow and you can now create a new lead without inputting the Company field value.

What is happening is that, we are using the newly created custom Company field to refer to any company details. The standard one is there but we are **not** using it, in this case, all leads Company (Standard Field) value will be "test" (or whatever value you assigned in the flow, it doesn't matter, you can even put "a", because we are not using this field, we are just populating it since it is required) and Company__c value will be whatever you put in from the record page.

This is just a general workaround, you might want to consider your flow starting conditions and etc, but the concept is the same.

I hope it helps! :)